# How to store basic usernames and passwords in LastPass

Tags: passwords, lastpass

I have checked several articles about which is the ultimate online password manager tool.

Almost all of them were praising LastPass as it can do *everything*.

Well, I'm a KeePass user so I'm used to store my password for pages, devices or softwares in the following form: *username and password*.

In KeePass, it is easy, I just add a new entry:

[image]

I installed LastPass and imported my KeePass username-password pairs.

Surprisingly, all my entries are *converted to notes*.

Not username-password pairs, they became simple notes.

Well, I wanted to add a new entry - and I can only add a site or a note (also, I have to *manually select the folder as it does not have a context menu*). No simple username-password entry whatsoever.

So basically LastPass is capable of keeping my *browser logins* and my *secret notes*? No basic username-password entry?

Comment: Incorrect.  install the browser plugin, logged into website, when prompted save the site.

Comment: @Ramhound Have you read the post? I want my _password manager_ to remember my wifi access, my office account and my garage lock code as a username-password entry. What should it be about a _website_?

Comment: You can use Notes but LastPass is designed to save passwords for websites.  There might still be the application by LastPass that allows you to use it for application passwords but that's about it

Comment: What a market hole...I think I'll create a company monday morning that fills the gap. Serious mistake...

Comment: There are varying secure note types in LastPass. When you add one, you can pick credit card, WiFi, bank account, etc.